# How to find Near Rectilinear Halo Orbits (NHROs)?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, astrodynamics, three-body

Looking all the good questions and answers in this site referent to CR3BP dynamics, periodic orbits, state transition matrices, etc. I wonder:

**what algorithm or steps do I have to follow to find the so famous Near Rectilinear Halo Orbtis (NHROs)?**.

Assume that I already know how to simulate CR3BP dynamics and basic shooting methods (that exploits the symettry of the CR3BP) to find generic halo orbits. I just want to know strategies to catch these orbits with such interesting stability properties.

Related questions include:

1. [Are (some) Halo Orbits actually Stable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15268/are-some-ha)
2. [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24019/what-is-a-near-rectilinear-halo-orbit)
3. [Why is a near rectilinear halo orbit proposed for LOP-G (formerly known as Deep Space Gateway?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23992/why-is-a-near-rectilinear-halo-orbit-proposed-for-lop-g-formerly-known-as-deeplo-orbits-actually-stable)
4. [How to best think of the State Transition Matrix, and how to use it to find periodic Halo orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20590/how-to-best-think-of-the-state-transition-matrix-and-how-to-use-it-to-find-peri)

Comment: Not really a full answer, but I happen to know one of the people who generates NRHOs for the Orion program.  Pretty sure this is one of the papers relevant to doing so.  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20170001352.pdf

Comment: @Julio I've just re-read your question, slowly, all the words, all the way through ;-) It's very clear and well written and indeed I've aimed too low and *mis-answered*. I've deleted my answer here, and I'll use it for a different question. Deleted answers still "there" and visible to people with 10k rep. Since some can't read it, I'll repeat part of your comment: "*As a matter of fact, when asking this question I was more interested in the continuation steps to specifically find NRHOs and if the stop procedure (when you have found them) is based on both qualitative and quantitative metrics?*"