# Details about traveling from EM-L2 to SE-L1

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, lagrangian-points, delta-v

Would the optimal time to launch be when the Moon was on the opposite side of the Earth from the Sun?  What direction would be optimal leaving EM-L2, radially away from the moon?

[Is the last line of this table a reasonable approximation of the delta-v required?](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/appmissiontable.php) [image]

If the launch used the minimal delta-v, and took place in the middle of Moon's umbra, how long would it take to emerge into the sunlight?

Comment: This is a great question! There are many Q&A here for how to calculate or estimate delta-v's for more classical transfer schemes based on a sequence of ellipses, and for low-thrust spirals from circular orbit to infinity ([and beyond!](https://youtu.be/K1Oes9b5VFI)) but I don't think we have *self-contained answers* within the site that explain how to address this kind of problem (libration-point start, end, or both) *mathematically*, without pointing off-site for the calculation itself.

Comment: @uhoh Do you know if those off-site options would be highly technical, or accessible to those with a few intro level undergraduate physics classes?  Do you know of any specific sites?

Comment: I don't know what "those off-site options" means. All I know is Stack Exchange. You can ask more questions here or ask something open-ended in the [Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) to get  several people's opinions.

Comment: @uhoh You said, "without pointing off-site for the calculations."  I assumed you meant websites off of Stack Exchange.  No matter.  I didn't know about Pod Bay, I will check it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, some users here answer questions with "the answer is in post x on my blog, where I have an excel file..." I meant that It would be great someone would answer with a real, proper Stack Exchange answer within this site. There is one blog though that may be of particular interest to you http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/ the author is also a user here. [@HopDavid](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/2848/hopdavid). You can search the blog for key words, and search @HopDavid's questions and answers.

Comment: I just ran across an example of an "off-site answer" https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5316/12102 It's a perfectly fine answer, but you need to go off site and then run a spreadsheet in your computer to get the goodies.

Comment: @uhoh Of what should I run a spreadsheet?  I'm missing what you are referring to on that link.

Comment: no, you don't need to run anything. I was just showing that as an example of what I meant by an "off-site answer". It's not an answer to your main question, it just addresses the question you [asked in this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35545/details-about-traveling-from-em-l2-to-se-l1?noredirect=1#comment111854_35545), nothing more.

Comment: Let me try my KSP-based hunch on how to achieve that transfer best. A prograde burn at the 'night side' of Earth, pulling the craft out of EM-L2, and bringing into an elliptical Earth orbit with apoapsis at SE-L1. Then a retrograde burn at SE-L1 to just stop there and remove the arrival speed. Pretty much like a Hohmann transfer except departure takes less fuel as you tumble out of L2 gravity peak, and arrival braking instead of speeding up.